# Win32_Process.Getowner() very slow on a specific machine

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0, wmi-query, wmic

I'm trying to get the owner of a process by running this WMI query in powershell:

```
$processes = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |where{$_.name -like "*notepad*"}
$objcol = @()
foreach ($process in $processes) 
{
    $owner = $process.GetOwner().User
    #$owner = $process.ProcessId
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value ($owner)
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name pid -Value $process.ProcessId
    $owner = "" 
    $objcol += $obj
} 
$objcol | ft  owner, pid -AutoSize |Out-String -Width 300
```

But somehow on a specific machine (windows server 2008), it takes 30mins to finish this short script. If I remove the line "$owner = $process.GetOwner().User", and replace it with "$owner = $process.ProcessId", the query can finish in a few seconds. But on other machines (Windows Server 2003, 2008, 2012), there is no such kind of problem. So I think it has something to do with this Win32_Process.Getowner() method but not sure how.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like it's taking a long time to resolve the SIDs to an account name.  I'd suspect it's gotten latched onto a DC in a galaxy far, far away.  In any case, you can try switching from .GetOwner() to Get-OwnerSID(), and then resolving the SIDS locally.

Comment: @mjolinor thanks for answering. Do you how I can find out which DC this server get latched onto? "echo %logonserver%" in command line? The result for this problematic server is the same with the other good servers.

Comment: @mjolinor, I tried to use getOwnerSID(), but it doesn't not help to improved the performance. I tried to use just "Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "name = 'notepad.exe'"|select processid,processname|ft" and the performance is different enough. On the problematic machine, it always takes about 40 seconds. While on the other machines, it takes with 1 second. Do you know why?

Comment: @mjolinor, if I add "{$_.getownersid().sid}" in the select statement, the time needed for the problematic machine would be 300seconds. While on other machines, the time is still about 1 second... It's so weird, I'm feeling that the  wmi query is slow as hell...

Answer (score 0):

You can try an easier way, install PowerShell v4 and use

Get-Process -name *notepad* **-IncludeUserName**